# Easiest way to select within a model using JPQL

Tags: sql, hibernate, jpa, playframework, jpql

I have hibernate database with three model:

```
Article - which has is part of multiple categories (EDIT).
Category - which contains articles, and is part of an App
App - which has different categories
```

I want to select all articles which have a category of a specific app.
So I am trying to create something like:

```
find("ANY categories.app = ?", app).fetch();
```

Something like this worked for me with CoreData, but obvious not with JPA, and I don't seem to be able to find how to do this.

Edit:
To clarify:
in Articles:

```
    @ManyToMany
    public List<Category> categories;
```

in Category:

```
    @ManyToOne
    public App app;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "categories")
    public List<Article> articles;
```

in App:

```
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "app")
    public List<Category> categories;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select a from Article a where a.category.app = ?
```

Read http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#queryhql

Comment: When I try that, I get: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: illegal attempt to dereference collection [article0_.id.categories] with element property reference [app] [SELECT a from models.Article a WHERE a.lastUpdate > ? AND a.categories.app = ?]. (categories instead of category, as it is a many-to-many relationship)

Comment: So, an article has many categories, is that right? You said that a category contained several articles. So it's a ManyToMany association. In this case you need an explicit join: select a from Article a inner join a.categories c where c.app = ?. This is very well explained in the documentation I linked to. Read it, that's how you'll learn.

Comment: I got the shivers when you mentioned inner join, bad memories from a way gone past... Thanks! I couldn't remember it anymore, and didn't know where to start. Sometimes I do things an 'old-fasion' way I used to code SQL, which is to expensive. So thanks for pointing out this is the way, it works! The document is very helpful! (and sorry for not stating the case clear)

Comment: The point where to start is always the same: reading the documentation.